# Find difference between todays date and time to another date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, twig, hubl

I'm trying to find the date and time difference between two dates (and times). I'm trying to implement a countdown (to the event date) feature but coming across issues with my approach.

**Note**: Some of the variables defined below are in `HuBL`, `HuBL` can be used in `Javascript` so as long as they're in the same file.

### Here's my current approach:

**1. How I'm obtaining the data and time**

In `HubSpot`, I have a database table. Within that table, I have a column which is of type `date and time`. For reference, the value in this field is the following:

[image]

I've ran a `for loop` to obtain its `date` **and** `time` as separate variables (`event_date` is the column name in the database table):

```
{% for data in table_query %}
  {% set event_date    = data.event_date|datetimeformat('%B %e, %Y') %}
  {% set event_time    = data.event_date|datetimeformat('%H %M') %}
{% endfor %}
```

To see the `datetimeformat` parameters I've used - [see the documentation here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/hubl/filters)

Doing `{{ event_date }}` prints: **September 7, 2020**
Doing `{{ event_time }}` prints: **11 59**

**2. Now that I have the date and time in vars, how I'm trying to find the difference**

**In hero.html**:

```html
{% for data in table_query %}
   {% set event_date    = data.event_date|datetimeformat('%B %e, %Y') %}
   {% set event_time    = data.event_date|datetimeformat('%H %M') %}
{% endfor %}


<script>

  var event_date = new Date('{{ event_date }}');
  var todays_date = new Date();


  function getDifferenceInDays(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  }

  function getDifferenceInHours(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60);
  }

  function getDifferenceInMinutes(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / (1000 * 60);
  }

  function getDifferenceInSeconds(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / 1000;
  }

  console.log(getDifferenceInDays(event_date, todays_date));
</script>
```

**My issues:**

With the above, I'm getting a `console.log` of `NaN`. I'm trying to get the results in `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` because I'm dividing it for the countdown to event timer.

I'm am totally lost on how will be able to check against the event time - trying to get the countdown timer as accurate as possible, to countdown to event start, but unsure on how I can do this

**Note**: Tagging `twig` too as syntax is similar to `HubL`

Comment: Hmm try: `var event_date = new Date({{ event_date }});` (Removing the single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in event_data. you are getting maybe string beside integer.
for example, if you hardcoded the new date you will get an answer to the console.

```
var event_date = new Date(2020, 08, 03, 12, 15, 30);
  var todays_date = new Date();


  function getDifferenceInDays(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  }

  function getDifferenceInHours(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60);
  }

  function getDifferenceInMinutes(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / (1000 * 60);
  }

  function getDifferenceInSeconds(event_date, todays_date) {
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(todays_date - event_date);
    return diffInMs / 1000;
  }

  console.log(getDifferenceInDays(event_date, todays_date));
```

https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/jOqNPMm
(check the console)

Answer (score 0):

Your NaN is coming from providing a string to your date constructor that's wrapped around your template rendering output

```
var event_date = new Date('{{ event_date }}');
// should be
var event_date = new Date({{ event_date }});
```

I think what you really need here is to just use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

Here's a simple days different example. The moment docs are quite extensive on durations: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var ms = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms).asDays();
```